# Indy multi port tcp doesn't receive data in specific port

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, tcpserver, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a TCP server to read data from some different ports.

The port 55000 is connected to a hardware device, but other ports will get data from software clients.

My code is shown below.

All ports except 55000 are working good but i don't get any data on 55000. Wire-Shark is showing every thing is OK on TCP layer, also a Math-Lab software can receive data but Indy cannot.

How can i find and fix the problem?

```
ccsReCStatus := false;
offReCStatus := false;
case AContext.Binding.Port of
      55000: begin
              repeat
                  aByte := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
                  inputOfflineStr := inputOfflineStr + chr(aByte);
                  if inputOfflineStr.Length>1000 then
                  begin
                    TThread.Synchronize(
                    nil,
                    procedure
                      begin
                          Memo14.Lines.Add( inputOfflineStr );
                          inputOfflineStr:='';
                      end);
                    end;
              until offReCStatus = true;
      end;
      35758: begin
            inputCcsStr :='';
            repeat
                  aByte := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
                  if aByte=$C0 then
                  begin
                      TThread.Synchronize(
                      nil,
                      procedure
                      begin
                          memo14.Lines.Add( datetimetostr(now) + ' :' + inputCcsStr );
                          inputCcsStr:='';
                      end);
                  end
                  else
                  begin
                      inputCcsStr := inputCcsStr +  aByte.ToHexString;
                      AbLED482.Tag := DateTimeToUnix(now);
                      AbLED482.Checked := true;
                  end;
            until ccsReCStatus = true;
      end;
      2222: begin
            RStr:='';
          repeat
                aByte := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
                if (aByte = $C0) and (RStr='') then
                begin
                  RStr:='';
                end
                else
                if (aByte = $C0) and (RStr<>'') then
                begin
                  TThread.Synchronize(
                  nil,
                  procedure
                  begin
                       memo14.Lines.Add( RStr );
                       RStr := '';
                  end);
                end
                else
                begin
                    RStr:=RStr+chr(aByte);
                end;
          until ccsReCStatus = true;
        end;
end;
```

Comment: The only way you wouldn't receive any bytes on port 55000 is if either 1) no bytes are being sent to that port, or 2) your server is not actually listening to that port. Wireshark can verify the first, Netstat can verify the second. Are you sure you are not receiving any bytes? Your code only shows the bytes when 1001 have been received, how many bytes is the hardware actually sending? Is `OnExecute` even being called for port 55000? Also, are you running Matlab at the same time as your server? You can't have multiple servers on the same port at the same time.

Comment: On a side note, you need to use `TThread.Synchronize()` when updating `AbLED482`. And when you reset `inputOfflineStr`, `inputCcsStr`, and `RStr`, that can be done outside of `Synchronize()`

Comment: i tested my server on 55000 with other software and it worked well. how can i know Is OnExecute even being called for port 55000?its a code block and other port are working correctly , the hardware device is sending unlimited data until disconected.

Comment: "*i tested my server on 55000 with other software and it worked well.*" - then the problem is not with your code. Double check the network connection of the hardware device. "*how can i know Is OnExecute even being called for port 55000?*" - that is what the debugger is for. Or add logging to your code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i used this code in a new vcl project and it worked , but in original project (up to 100k line code) not working yet! can this be a conflict with other components?! if yes how can this be troubleshooted ?

Comment: "*can this be a conflict with other components*" - not likely,  but anything is possible. You need to debug and see what is actually happening. "*how can this be troubleshooted*" - I've pointed out several things you need to check. You haven't answered those questions yet. Does netstat show your server listening on port 55000? Does Wireshark show a valid connection on port 55000? Does the debugger show your `OnExecute` handler being called for port 55000? Is your code able to read any bytes on port 55000? Is the code hanging on `Synchronize()` perhaps?